# Get horizontal padding/margin part of SASS variable

Tags: sass

There's a SASS variable defined as follows:

```
$section-padding: 3rem 1.5rem !default
```

It is then used elsewhere as a padding value which works fine:

```
padding: $section-padding;
```

How do I dynamically get hold of the `1.5rem` value? Is there some way to extract it, supposing the `$section-padding` variable will always contain a shorthand padding/margin definition?

I cannot split the value into two separate variables as `$section-padding` is defined like this in a third-party CSS framework ([Bulma](https://bulma.io)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was on the right track, but a mistake in a `calc()` call where I was using it made it blow up.

SASS has the concept of [lists](https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/07/15/understanding-sass-lists). A variable is considered a list if it contains space or comma separated values. You can then extract the desired part by using the `nth()` function (1-based indexing):

```
nth($section-padding, 2)
```

Note that to use this in a `calc()` the function call should be wrapped in `#{}` (which was my mistake):

```
padding: calc(200px + #{nth($section-padding, 2)});
```